How do I uninstall a Steam game without logging into Steam?
I need to give a former employee laptop to another employee. I've been told not to reimage or reinstall Windows.
The laptop has many Steam games installed. When I use Windows 11 "Add/Remove Programs" it starts the Steam app and asks me to log on, which I cannot do.
Does anyone know how to uninstall these games without having to log onto Steam?
I tried uninstalling Steam, but that left all the games. If I try to uninstall the games it presents the error that it cannot find the Steam application.

Have you tried reinstalling the steam app, making an account for yourself, and then logging in to that account?

Pass my downvote to whoever told you to not reinstall the system. The answer to the question is simple, also, but won't give you any hints so that you follow/promote some awful practice.

@Destroy666 - Thank you. I'll press harder for the "it needs to be re-imaged" solution.


... repurpose an ex-employees laptop ... I've been explicitly told not to reimage or reinstall Windows.

I call this a "Technical Solution in search of a Requirement" and, in this day and age, I have to say it's a particularly dumb one.
You don't say where in the world you are, but if you've ever come across the phrase General Data Protection Regulations, or GDPR, then I would suggest that Steam is the least of your worries.
If this machine has any Personal Data on it and you hand it over to another User who has no business accessing that data, you've just created yourself a Reportable Data Breach.  You know, those "fines of 20 million Euros or 4% of your company's annual turnover" affairs.
And then there's the possibility of all sorts of malware that might be on this machine.
If there's something on the machine that someone really wants to keep, then let them identify it and copy it.
Then, treat the machine as compromised, "burn" it and reimage it.
